# Recuperar imagen de carpeta storage en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un problema que no le encuentro solución, he guardado la ruta de una imagen, que almaceno en la carpeta storage/empleados, al recuperarlo en local funciona correctamente pero cuando lo subi a un hosting me sale el siguiente error:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

tengo configurado el archivo filesystem de esta manera:

```
'empleados' =>[
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('empleados'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/empleados/',
    ],
```

lo intento recuperar de esta manera:

```
<img style="width: 50%; height: 50%" src="{{url('/')}}/{{$usuario->empleados->foto}}" width="100%"/>
```

Alguien sabe como se puede recuperar.

Answer (score 2):

Para poder acceder a las imágenes estando en un servidor tienes que crear un enlace simbólico de tu carpeta storage.

```
$ php artisan storage:link
```

[Documentación laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: ya lo intente de esa manera, pero no me lo reconoce. Creo que es porque deje solo a la carpeta public dentro de public_html y todo lo demas esta fuera de esa carpeta